# Auto Build Migrations in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, entity-framework

I'm build an app using Blazor Webserver

I try to build an app and Db using Docker (compose). I complete the deploy of the implementation ( run the app and the SQL Server in a containers) but, when i don't know how i can run the migrations (code firts) to generate the databases require on production.

(when i run the app in deploy mode, i can build a new migration using the package manager console, but i don´t know how to build in a release enviroment)

(also 1 of my DataBases is administrate by a .ddl and the other is administrate by the "main project [the blazor project]")

Exist any form to "auto generate" the databases with the migrations, when the DB don't exist    and the app have connection with the DB?

Comment: I see this [post](https://codebuckets.com/2020/08/14/applying-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-docker-container/) , but i¿m not sure if this is the correct way

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```

before

```
app.Run();
```